# Testing for valid objectId

Tags: javascript, mongodb, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm using jest to test a mongoDB ObjectID.
In the function I check if the id is valid. Then I return the ObjectId.

In my test I'm expecting to get a string using `valueOf()` of the ObjectId, but the test is failing:

```
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb'

const safeObjectId = (id) => {
  return ObjectId.isValid(id) ? new ObjectId(id) : null
}

it('should return ObjectId if it is valid', () => {
  const result = safeObjectId('5a1154523a6bcc1d245e143d')
  expect(typeof result).toBe('object')
  expect(result.valueOf()).toEqual('5a1154523a6bcc1d245e143d')
})
```

But I do get the error

```
Expected value to equal:
  "5a1154523a6bcc1d245e143d"
Received:
  "5a1154523a6bcc1d245e143d"

Difference:
  Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received object.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the 'str' attribute:

```
const safeObjectId = (id) => {
  return ObjectId.isValid(id) ? new ObjectId(id) : null
}

it('should return ObjectId if it is valid', () => {
  const result = safeObjectId('5a1154523a6bcc1d245e143d')
  expect(typeof result).toBe('object')
  expect(result.str).toEqual('5a1154523a6bcc1d245e143d')
})
```

From the docs... https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Access the str attribute of an ObjectId() object, as follows:

```
ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea").str
```

p.s. It's bad practice to have multiple assertions in a single test, I would move the object check and value check into two separate tests like so...

```
const safeObjectId = (id) => {
  return ObjectId.isValid(id) ? new ObjectId(id) : null
}

it('should return an object', () => {
  const result = safeObjectId('5a1154523a6bcc1d245e143d')
  expect(typeof result).toBe('object')
})

it('should return the correct ObjectId', () => {
  const result = safeObjectId('5a1154523a6bcc1d245e143d')
  expect(result.str).toEqual('5a1154523a6bcc1d245e143d')
})
```

Comment: The last test is receiving `undefined`. I also read that part of the docs and tried to use `.str` before.

Comment: What does this do..

const result = safeObjectId('5a1154523a6bcc1d245e143d').str
  expect(result).toEqual('5a1154523a6bcc1d245e143d').

Comment: It's the same: undefined. The first test is passing, so there is a object at all...

Comment: try converting result to a string toString() before the assertion - I remember seeing this once when asserting mongo where values are identical but === will still fail as the type is different i.e an object vs a string

Comment: If I do `console.log(result)` in the first test I'm getting `5a1154523a6bcc1d245e143d` output. I don't see the object. But the test is passing - which is checking for an object type. Don't understand that.

Comment: expect(result.toString()).toEqual('5a1154523a6bcc1d245e143d')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159566/discussion-between-zinc-and-user3142695).

Comment: Why is a bad practice having multiple assert in one test?